# How to determine WinForm is being focus or not while press HotKey?

Tags: c#, focus

I set Ctrl + Space to do this:

- If Form1 is focus, hide it.
- If Form1 is being hidden, or it isn't being focus, show and focus it (SetForegroundWindow).

I almost finish my work, the only thing is I don't know how to detemine if my Form1 is in focus or not. Can you help me? Thank a lot!!!

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/d9b4d96d-a0f9-4e8c-b741-2f914e59a54b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle in [Form.Activated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated.aspx) event when the form is focus..

Similarly, when form is out of focus, handle it on [Form.Deactivate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.deactivate.aspx) event....

Comment: It only determine if Form become focus, but not when Form lose Focus